# stuck with save file directories during tests in C#

Tags: c#, .net, testing, directory

I have created a c# solution ("biblioTk"). Then, I added some other projects : "biblioTk2", and biblioTkTests which contains test methods. all this worked well until I needed to manage save files. In my test methods, I would like to test if the save file exists, or to delete it (to prepare the project and see if the file is created when s/o click on the "save" button).

The test methods call a tool class ("FileManager") which purpose is to handle the file management. In a method of this class, I use `appDir=Environment.CurrentDirectory;` but this method doesn't return the correct path: is returns ""C:\Users\lolve\source\repos\biblioTk\TestResults\lolve_DESKTOP-9AOEDTO 2018-10-12 11_10_24\Out""
What I want is a path to the current executing exe file, as in "C:\Users\lolve\source\repos\biblioTk2\bin\Debug\biblioTk2.exe"

(here is the project's view is visual studio): [image: here]

I think there is a huge problem : the directory returned by Environment.CurrentDirectory is not the same when I launch the app and when I debug it...

here is my FileManager class:

```
public class FileManager
    {
        private string SAVEFILE = "datas.saved";
        public string appDir = null;
        public string pathToSaveFile = null;

        public FileManager()
        {
            //appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            appDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            pathToSaveFile = Path.Combine(appDir, SAVEFILE).Replace("file:\\","");
        }

        public Boolean saveFileExists()
        {
            Assembly ass = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == "biblioTk2");
            return File.Exists(SAVEFILE);
            // Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + SAVEFILE
            //Console.WriteLine(typeof(AmazonManager).Assembly);
            //"file:\\"+pathToSaveFile
        }

        public void saveToFile(ObservableCollection<Book> books)
        {                
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            //Stream stream = new FileStream(SAVEFILE, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            using (Stream stream=new FileStream(pathToSaveFile,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, books.ToArray());
            }
        }

        public void deleteSavedFile()
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(pathToSaveFile);
        }

        public void loadFromFile(ObservableCollection<Book> books)
        {    
            if (!saveFileExists())
                return;

            Book[] booksArray;
            IFormatter formatterRestore=new BinaryFormatter();
            using (Stream streamRestore =
                new FileStream(pathToSaveFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                booksArray = (Book[])formatterRestore.Deserialize(streamRestore);
                books.Clear();
                foreach (var book in booksArray)
                {
                    books.Add(book);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the path to your executable, you can use this:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: are you sure? A debugging session setting a variable with this expression gave me the path of visual studio + "common7\IDE" which is not what I was expecting

Comment: As long as you haven't changed your Output path in the Project Properties the returned path should end with …\bin\Debug. That's where the program is compiled to and that's from where the debugging session is started. (afaik)

Comment: maybe it is related to the test project : the tests aren't located in the same place as the program.

Comment: the test project is referenced as "coded ui test project"

Comment: perhaps I found the reason, but not the remedy; the MainWindow create an instance of the FileManager class, at its startup. On its own, the test class creates too an instance, so when I launch tests there are two instances of the FileManager class in memory, and it is shown at the awkward behavior :

Comment: when the FileManager instance is called from the MainWindow instance, the default path (for e.g. in the FileStream constructor, if I give it as the file path only "datas.saved" I mean the name of the file) is in .../bin/Debug; whereas when called from the test class is gives the odd path I provided above. I maybe need a little trick in order to use the same instance in both cases but at the time being I don't see.